# How do you make sure that yor medication is legal to travel with?

Tags: drugs

I have certain medication I have to drink every night, if I where to travel overseas how would I insure that if my bags are searched and they find the pills they dont decide it is drugs?

Answer (score 3):

Put on your carry on baggage (if it is allowed for the quantity). Keep always a doctor prescription.

Remember to check if the medication are allowed on the traveling country (there are some restriction on some kind of medications [mostly on opiate], and quantity (keep some extra in case of delays, but not too much). Having original packing and somewhere the active matter (so the original medicament notice sheet) helps a lot.

If you have too much liquids, there are several options:

- On checked baggage, on original packing, and better it these are sealed. From package, and quantity, the custom should understand that it is a medicament.  Note: there are two checks: one for security (so without you). But custom check is done with you, after baggage claim, so you can explain.
- You buy on the destination country the extra medications. In general it is good to pre-check the name of the medication on destination country (checked baggage are lost, ...). Because of different names, do not assume that in pharmacy they will know what it is the prescribed medicament (a copy of the medicament notice will help, usually there are some indication of makers, patent holder, linked authorization numbers, and active matter, so that pharmacy can find out the name used on destination country. Sometime it is easier (especially on long travel) to buy the medicament on destination country.
- You may contact your air carrier. They could make exceptions and help. OTOH this requires a lot more paperwork, and discussion. For a private person often this is not a good option. But this help you to have better documentation, not to pass the custom.

Comment: What to do if you don't have prescription?

Comment: It depends. If it can have side effect (or dangerous), probably it should have a prescription, so better to check if the prescription is needed on destination country, or getting one prescription from own country (pharmacy could write something, if it is not mandatory). If it is not dangerous, you may see it as health food, and not as medicament, so check regular food restriction.  Note: prescriptions are not much about health effects, but if taking medicament should be controlled (for health reason), dangerous (e.g. addictive, or just good for some people) or for insurance reasons.

Comment: Medications are specifically exempted from carry-on luggage liquid rules, although you will need to show the prescription.  TSA: https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2013/09/24/tsa-travel-tips-tuesday-traveling-medication

Comment: A real case are prescription-free influenza drugs containing ephedrine, which is forbidden drug in some countries. In Poland you can buy them in groceries...

Comment: *Keep always a doctor prescription.*  But I gave the prescription to the pharmacist so that they could fill the prescription.

Comment: @RonJohn: ask then to make a copy (it is marked as copy, so you cannot use twice), but it shows that you also brought the medicament. You can ask also later. They should keep the prescription for some time. I really recommend always to have it, also in case you forgot some medicament.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to take medicine regularly then you must have doctors prescription. Therefore, you carry your pills then you must carry the prescription. This would not be a problem if you carry a valid document(prescription).

Comment: And what with drugs available without prescription?

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g Keep it in the original bottle.

Comment: *Keep always a doctor prescription.*  But I gave the prescription to the pharmacist so that they could fill the prescription.